# Create custom query to get specific columns in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql

I tried to get rows from table visitor Postgresql database. But I don't need all columns, but at the moment to execute custom query, it does not work.

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT visitor_id, first_name, last_name, email, company, country_id FROM Visitor", Visitor.class);
List<Visitor> result = query.getResultList();
return result;
```

The errors console shows me are:

> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name city was not found
>   in this ResultSet.

```
SELECT visitor_id, city, company, email, email_confirmed, first_name, 
       identification_number, identification_other, image, is_active, 
       job_title, last_name, mobile_number, password, phone_number, 
       province, country_id, created_by, identification_type_id
FROM visitor;
```

All the columns are there.  So what I do is call the function to get all rows and set it in another function called bindRegisterToDashboard();. It functions sets only six columns from the table to object visitorDashBoardViewModel, to show it on the view.

```
//service file code
for (Visitor item: getVisitors()) {
     visitorDashBoardViewModel.add(bindRegisterToDashboard(item);
}
return visitorDashBoardViewModel;
```

Visitor model:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long visitorId;

    private String identificationOther;
    private long identificationNumber;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private boolean emailConfirmed;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String mobileNumber;
    private String password;
    private String province;
    private String city;
    private String company;
    private String jobTitle;
    private Boolean isActive;
    private byte[] image;


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="identification_type_id")
    private IdentificationType identificationType;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", nullable = false)
    private Country country= new Country();
```

Comment: Hi Angel. could you -> \d+ tablename Or describe the table columns please + from the output it seems its not failing in the function. "From the hip" guess I'd say its in your manipulation of the result set.

Comment: I edited the quesion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't return instances of Visitor. It returns arrays of objects. So it shouldn't be a `TypedQuery<Visitor>`, but simply a `Query`.

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT v.visitorId, v.firstName, v.lastName, v.email, v.company, v.country.id FROM Visitor v");
List<Object[]> rows = query.getResultList();
// now, in each Object[], visitor_id is at index 0, first_name at index 1, etc.
```

Also, please, respect the Java naming conventions: id, firstName, lastName, etc.

If you want your query to return instances of Visitor, it should be

```
TypedQuery query = em.createQuery("SELECT v from Visitor v");
List<Visitor> visitors = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: The goal to execute the custom query is because it spends .2 seconds, and if I execute all columns query spends 14 seconds. I implements your answer but it shows me an error; java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode <| +-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'visitor_id' {originalText=visitor_id}<|

Comment: See my updated query. Does your entity has a field named visitor_id? I don't see how such a simple query could go from .2 seconds to 14 seconds just by having a few more selected columns. Unless maybe you have plenty of eagerly fetched associations in your entities. Post the code of Visitor in your question.

Comment: Your Visitor class doesn't have any visitor_id or last_name field. They're named visitorId and lastName. So obviously, the JPQL query is invalid. JPQL is NOT SQL. It works with entities and their fields, unlike SQL which works with tables and column names.

Comment: Read my previous comment. Read my answer. Read the error message.